# C++ Compare Method within a Class

Tags: c++

```
while(getline(INPUT,textLine))
  {
    Object* s = new Object(textLine);
    }
```

How would I hold a reference to the Object of the previous textLine so that I could compare the two in some compare method

`s.Compare(***);` <-- comparing the second iteration to the first

Note that `***` is of type Object

Comment: This is vague. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to keep track of the previous instance of Object?
Put it in a variable (called `t` below), and use the variable when you need it.
Remember to delete everything you allocate.

```
Object* s;
Object* t = NULL;

while(getline(INPUT,textLine))
{
    s = new Object(textLine);
    s->Compare(t);

    delete t; 
    t = s;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to keep the previous `Object*`. The implementation is basically the same as your code except `previousLine` should be of type `Object*` and you should have `previousLine = s;` at the end.

Comment: No, please don't advocate this *as is*. There are no deletes.

Comment: Edited to track the previous object, not the previous textLine.  Also added a delete.  Final memory cleanup after the loop ends is a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

first, see strcmp()

if you want to incorporate this into your "Object" class, which is a bad naming choice, overload the operators !=, ==, > or <, all of them, or only one of them, as you wish/need.
Comparison would then go like: if (s > s2) or similar.

Try reading a decent c++ book which covers basic topics as operator overloading and so on.

Comment: `strcmp` does not work on `std::string`s directly. You can just test them with `==`.

Comment: forgot to see that, but the question is so imprecise, i have no idea HOW he wants to compare them. let's hint him the fun with Locales and locale-aware string comparisons for umlauts, and such

Comment: @user875552: No matter how poorly-written a question is (and this one isn't *that* bad), answers still shouldn't have incorrect information in them.

Comment: Sure, i agree again. But he can compare std::string's through strcmp(). And i pointed to the problem with umlauts, etc so is aware of sorting that is not looking correct to him, because this is what most people (coding beginner) expect.

i also apologize for answering a bit sloppily and not very friendly